# "Rest is silent" hamlet

Tags: william-shakespeare, hamlet

So i got this ideea about it. It s something Socrates said  when he died. He ask to give a sacrifice to the healing god because the poison worked. Well he was sentenced to death for not believing in the gods. So as Socrates states with his last words so did Shakespeare with Hamlet last words. Is about the question science can t explain. Consciousness is put at rest. Same as Socrates. They both were the same. Would love to see other answers.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This post doesn't read like an actual *question* - it's more like sharing some thoughts, potentially an *answer* to the question about the meaning of "the rest is silence" (although not a very good answer either since it doesn't explain itself with clear arguments or references). You can learn more about how this site works in the [tour] - it's not a typical internet forum, as we're quite strict on the Q&A format here.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to answer on a old post but couldn t... i know what i said is true. cause i know how their mind works.. Shakespeare and Socrates.. they were both empaths...  something science can t explain too...  will try to to tell u this... when someone speak with them their mind through their eyes think of lots of posibilities and can read the person in front of them easily..  Will tell u this though.. Shakespeare lost his ability to writte when he moved from london, and Socrates 2nd wife was a narcisisst.. he didnt speak with her at home. Its anpattern u just cant see it.

Comment: Their jester mind never stoped working and i know how it is..

Comment: Before u comment.. i know u dont understand.. its not all literature... their life work wich everybody call genius.. for them was trauma most of their life... and death was an escape.